# Mirrored side is going through original side

Tags: mirror-modifier

I applied a *Mirror* modifier onto an object and I get this problem:

[image]

Comment: The mirror is set at your objects origin, move the origin and see what it does. Use the `Options` dropdown in the top left corner to `Affect only - Origins` in Object Mode

Comment: still does'nt work

Comment: @SatyaveerSinghNaruka: so pls provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: sorry and now i dont know how to do that too

Answer (score 1):

Select one vertex at the top of the model, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected*, go to object mode, right click on the model and choose *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*.